# What happen on the server side when i call an ajax?

Tags: .net, ajax, iis

The right question is, when I send an ajax request to the server side application, am I creating a new thread to process that request?

I am working with .net, so the web server that manage the application would be IIS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are indeed creating a new thread to process the request. As far as the server is concerned, there is practically no difference between a "regular" HTTP request and an AJAXy HTTP request (except that the headers in the request may be different).

Answer (score 0):

The server will simply receive the AJAX request normally as per any other HTTP POST or GET requests. In fact the client may send an AJAX request, but the server sees it as a normal HTTP request.

Server threading settings for AJAX are as per your usual HTTP settings.